# Loop problems parsing xml tree

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I need to parse many xml trees sequentially... I did a 'for' loop and it works perfectly for the first file, bur when starting the second it just takes forever and never prints the answer or follows for the other files.

I have 3 files that are all copies from a same file with diffente names to try the loop, the files are named as follow:

Medline_01.xml
Medline_02.xml
Medline_03.xml

---

I'm trying the followign loop:

---

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree    
import os

path = '/Users/brunap/Desktop/Work/Medline'   
listing = os.listdir(path)   
for file in listing:   
      if file.endswith('.xml'):    
           print file        
           data = os.path.join(path, file)    
           tree=etree.parse(data)    
           root = tree.getroot()    
           print root        
           print ""
```

---

It gives me the following result

---

Medline_01.xml
< Element 'PubmedArticleSet' at 0x10878bd80 >

Medline_02.xml

P.S.:And from this I wait for 2h and nothing happens. The first one took 15min

some one can help me with that?

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, but general idea: Do you have to close the file just processed in order to open the next one?  Or, is the next file open in another process?

Comment: Actualy I don't think the file is open in another process, but would be nice if I did that, I'll try close the file before goes to the other, but can you tell me how do I put them in parallel analysis ?

Comment: Like I said, not a python programmer, but in general, define a thread that takes a file name and processes it.  Then get the list of files and for each file, instantiate a thread and give it a file name.

Comment: closing is not working.... or maybe I'm not doing wrght. I've just started with python.... so there are a ot of thing i still dont know.... do you have some ideia how to close? I tried ' close()' and 'close(data)' and 'close(tree)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the script was fine, the problem was that the files were super big and the memory of the computer didn't handle running the script killing it and never following. When tried in an HPC cluster it works perfectly and much faster.

Thank for the sugestion any way, help me with other problems I had. :)